# Automatically checking system performance

Tags: hardware, performance

Is there any program out there for Ubuntu that check system performances and specs?

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about cpu usage, see `top` and `htop`.

If you are asking about benchmarking, you could install `GtkPerf` or any number of benchmarking tools...

Comment: And Yes that's what I'm asking,  Thanks for sharing!